# Cannot display Fetched JSON data from Web API call since backslashes are in response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC application to make a Web API call (GET request) to fetch JSON data.  I'm able to retrieve the data but when it comes back, there are now backslashes within the JSON data.

**C# Controller:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("company-info/companyinfogetapidata")]
        public ActionResult CompanyInfoGetApiData(string name, int CompanyCode, string city, string state, int zip)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL_BASE");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var request = client.GetAsync("URL_PATH");                        

            return Json(request.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            

        }
```

When I use Stackify Prefix to see responses that are returned from the Server, I get JSON data that looks like this:

```
"{\n\"results\":[\n{\n\t\"name\":\"Company  XYZ\",\n\t\"providerName\": \"Company Provider Info\",
```

It should look like this:

```
{"results":[{"name":"Company  XYZ", "providerName": "Company Provider Info",
```

Originally I was ok with just using the backslashes but the reason why I want to remove them is because when I try to use this returned data within a AJAX Success function, the JSON data attributes are not being read properly.  I get an error that says `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` when I try to access `name` from within my foreach loop.

AJAX Code:

```
         $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url:"../companyfindergetapidata",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {DATA_HERE},
                    error:function(e){alert("nope"+e);},
                    success: function (xhr_request) {                        

                        var fetched_data = xhr_request["results"];

                        var i;
                        var iLength = xhr_request.length;

                        for (i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {

             // THIS IS WHERE I GET AN ERROR "Cannot read property '0' of undefined

                            $("#CompanyFinderResultsContainer").append("<p>Name:&nbsp;" + fetched_data[i].name + "</p>");
                        }


                    }
                });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some editing, this is closer to your original code.  Note the added using;

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


[HttpGet]
[Route("company-info/companyinfogetapidata")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult CompanyInfoGetApiData(string name, int CompanyCode, string city, string state, int zip)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL_BASE");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var request = client.GetAsync("URL_PATH");                
        var json = request.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        json = JToken.Parse(json).ToString();

        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);         
    }
```

Comment: When I try putting in this line `var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);`, I keep getting an error within Visual Studio saying `'HttpRequestResponse' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse'`

Comment: try it now. Back to ActionResult, explicitly used NewtonSoft.Json to parse the return value you're handling.

Comment: This is actually spacing out the JSON and creating data that looks like this: `"{\r\n  \"results\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"name\":`

Comment: Bloody hell.  All this is an issue because the json is serialized twice.  I reckon your best bet is to populate an object hierarchy from the json you receive from Request and then return `Json(objectHierarchy, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

I know it's ugly but your alternative is string manipulation and that's never fun.

Comment: I actually found a way to parse this out correctly using your method.  I'm going to write a response and accept your answer in a bit.  Thanks!